# Windows Service Alternatives For Automatic Application Startup

Tags: sql-server, azure, asp.net, windows-service

I've written an ASP.Net MVC / SignalR web application written in C# which I'm hosting on an Azure virtual machine. It's also got a SQL-Server instance on it and three Windows Services. Despite the client-side being fully asynchronous, it's pretty slow because of the amount of memory and CPU resources that SQL Server and the three Windows Services are taking. I've not got a massive budget so I can't afford to upgrade to a VM with more CPUs and memory, so I'm looking for ways to split the application up. I can probably get cheap hosting for the client-side because it doesn't do anything intensive, but the Windows Services work really hard and do a lot of writes to the database. I'm using the Windows Services because the application needs a lot of autonomous data processing to be done and if there is a server reset, I need to ensure that they automatically restart afterwards. I know it's opinion-based, but I just need alternatives that I can investigate for myself.

Comment: Maybe look into using Azure SQL Database rather than running SQL Server on the VM instance?

Comment: Yes, definately look at Azure SQL. Depending on how demanding your DB is it could be pretty cheap